# Failure to retrieve data from ajax-post on PHP page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to pass a collection of parameters to a PHP page to be processed, from a JavaScript function:

```
entries: "test data from JavaScript"
```

In my PHP page I'm trying to grab the value that was posted back to the page:

```
$_POST['entries']
```

but this keeps return 'emtpy', regardless of what I try to push through. I'm new to PHP so this might be a stupid thing to fix.

This is invoked from a button click like such:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){});
```

Should the  be wrapped in a form, as I don't see the need for this?

Update [full code]

```
var proxy = new ServiceProxy("submit.php");

$("#submit").click(function () {
     var store = $("#store_name").val();
     var contact = $("#contact_person").val();

     proxy.invoke("", { entries: store }, success, error, false);
     return false;
});
```

Note on the ServiceProxy. This proxy class wraps the default $.ajax {...} into a neat little proxy class, thanks to Rick Strahl over at west-wind. I've used this proxy class successfully in numerous single HTML and ASP.Net solutions in the past, so I don't it's the proxy service that's causing the issue.

Comment: Can you show the full code you are using to make the request?

Comment: We need to see the javascript code you are using the create the POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your using jQuery, so why not use their post function?

$.post("/file/location/post.php", { Name: "Hello", Email: "email@address.com" } );

Then in your php code you can use:

$_POST['Name'] and $_POST['Email']

Hope this helps.

Sorry, just seen your updated code - this should work:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
 var store = $("#store_name").val();
 var contact = $("#contact_person").val();
 $.post("submit.php", { entries: store } );
 return false; });
```